# Find two strings separated by n characters

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file containing many lines of text. I'm trying to find the line numbers for lines that contain *two* strings, which are **strictly** separated by `n` characters.

What I have so far:

```
grep -n "string1*string2" file.txt
```

Of course, that only prints out the line numbers where those two strings are adjacent. How do I enforce that n-character gap?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quantifier with a fixed number:

```
grep -nE 'string1.{10}string2' file
```

This will find `string1` and `string2` in same line with these two tokens separated by **exactly** 10 characters.

Comment: Ah, so easy. Thank you!

Comment: @m0skit0 can you expand on `doesn't work`? with ERE (-E option) the `{}` are meta characters and equivalent to `\{\}` of BRE

Comment: @m0skit0: Can you clarify what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`.\{N\}` where N is the number of characters, for example

```
grep -n "string1.\{2\}string2" file.txt
```